# TensorFlow: lambda use out of session

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am reading a snippet of TensorFlow [codes](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/28d3bf2fa7254037229035cac398632a5ef6fc24/src/compare.py#L85) (line 85-89) and get confused. I made some changes to clarify:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=gpu_memory_fraction)
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, log_device_placement=False))
    with sess.as_default():
        pnet = align.detect_face.create_mtcnn(sess, None)
out = pnet(img_y)
```

The `create_mtcnn` is defined as:

```
def create_mtcnn(sess, model_path):
    if not model_path:
        model_path,_ = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    with tf.variable_scope('pnet'):
        data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,None,None,3), 'input')
        pnet = PNet({'data':data})
        pnet.load(os.path.join(model_path, 'det1.npy'), sess)

    pnet_fun = lambda img : sess.run(('pnet/conv4-2/BiasAdd:0', 'pnet/prob1:0'), feed_dict={'pnet/input:0':img})

    return pnet_fun
```

My question is why `out = pnet(img_y)` does not throw an error since the graph and session is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Graph` and `Session` still exist after the `as_default` blocks exit, they just aren't the default anymore. You can run `session.close()` to close the `Session`.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> const = tf.constant(3.)
>>> session = tf.Session()
>>> session.run(const)
3.0
>>> session.close()
>>> session.run(const)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 906, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1064, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

Comment: In your case, if you remove `session.run(const)`, then it won't throw an exception any more. That is where I raise my question. And I want to know why `session.close()` does not work on this case.

Comment: That's a completely different question; your original question did not close the Session at all (see documentation for [as_default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default)). But to answer it looks like `session.close()` on an unused `Session` doesn't work, which is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to clarify the conversations between @Allen and me. `Session` still exist after `as_default`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    const = tf.constant(3.)
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        print(sess.run(const))

    print(sess.run(const))
    sess.close()
    print(sess.run(const))
```

You can find the result:

```
3.0
3.0
-------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
...
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

---

And you can repeat the bug through the following snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    const = tf.constant(3.)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print("No sess run within with block.")

    print(sess.run(const))
    sess.close()
    print(sess.run(const))
```

And the corresponding result is:

```
No sess run within with block.
3.0
-------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
...
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```